# Duplicate idle animation and change head orientation

Tags: animation

I have a character with an idle animation loop of about 30 frames looking straight ahead. Is there a reasonably easy way to duplicate the animation, but edit the duplicate to make the character look in a certain direction?

Basically I want create idle loops looking left/right, up/down etc to blend together at run time so the character tracks a moving point in space.

I guess it boils down to, is there a way to set the rotation of the head & neck bones in all the frames of an animation, allowing all the others to move as they were?

Comment: Have you tried the [NLA  (Nonlinear Animation) editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/index.html)? You can make 2 animation strips where the upper one ("look around") overwrites the underlying ("idle") animation, but only the head movement. Another example: Combine a walk cycle + a waving hand animation + a head nod + a blinking eyes animation, each on its own NLA strip. You can easily replace the "head nod" with a "head shake" this way.